# Database structure design with variable amounts of fields

Tags: mysql, database

For some kind of inventory system, a user can create a `item_type` which has certain properties, now the amount of properties is variable per type.. How should I go with the DBStructure on this? Just make a X amount of `propertyX` fields, or is there some other way to achieve flexibility in this way?

*note* I don't want to automaticly create tables, since that ain't managable.

Comment: what do properties look like?

Comment: how many item types do you have?

Comment: properties look like either INT, VARCHAR, or TEXT, with varying from 2 till perhaps 100 different properties (infinite wished)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a property table which is linked n:1 to the item_type table like this:

```
TABLE item_type (
  item_type_id INT,
  ... )

TABLE properties (
  property_id INT, -- primary key
  item_type_id INT, -- foreign key for item_type
  key NVARCHAR(max), -- adjust type to your needs
  value NVARCHAR(max) )
```

So each item_type can have 0:n properties.

Answer (score 4):

The usual way to do this is like this (pseudo-SQL):

```
create table property_types (
  property_id int primary key,
  name varchar,
  -- more info here
);

create table items (
  item_id int primary key,
  -- your item table
);

-- this table links a property value with an item
create table item_properties (
  item_id int,
  property_id int,
  property_value varchar,
  foreign key fk_item (item_id) references items (item_id),
  foreign key fk_property (property_id) references properties (property_id)
);
```

Optionally, you can have a unique constraint on item_properties (item_id, property_id) to ensure that every property is set only once per item

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve a dynamic number of properties by creating a `Properties` table with each property referencing your `Items` table. e.g.

```
Items Table

Id  Name


Properties Table

Id  ItemId  Name  Value
```

In this manner, you're not limited to a static number of properties, or even the same properties.  The `Properties` table would essentially be a dictionary table of name/value pairs with a strong tie to your `Items` table.