# Is this usage of foreign key correct and if not is there a solution?

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

For a project I have to design a database which can handle arbitrary an arbitrary amount of variables retrieved from different kinds of sensors (for instance, one sensor could give "x, y, z" while another sensor could return "x, y, z, voltage").
A text file would be a suitable solution, however I want to explore possibilities within the database itself.

When searching stack-overflow [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6762749/database-structure-design-with-variable-amounts-of-fields) might give me the solution.

```
Table: Session
["ID", startTime]

Table: Data1
["ID", SessionID, endTime] (in which the foreign key is SessionID)

Table: Data2
["ID", SessionID, endTime, x] (in which again the foreign key is SessionID)
```

Am I right to assume that in this case I can use both Data1 or Data2 as datatype in Session?

If this is not the case, is there a solution?

**Edit:**

to clarify, I have a sensor with an unknown amount of variables coming to my database.

in my database I have a session table, this table will contain an arbitrary amount of Data (from the sensor). I need to make sure that I have either a text file or (preferably) a table which can change in content, dependent on which sensor it retrieves its data from.

Comment: at this moment no database has been chosen, I am doing preliminary research. the two that I am thinking of are mySQL and SQLite. but this is not set in stone.

Comment: Why don't you use a single table for the data using a 4th nullable field for voltage? Then fields that have voltage null is equal sensor A and voltage not null sensor B.

Comment: the tables in the example are examples, I don't know the amount of variables needed.